# Angular 16: How do I change the size of Angular Material checkbox (MDC)?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular16

In what's now considered legacy Material I could set the checkbox size  as follows:

```
.mat-checkbox-frame {
  width: 1.5rem;
}
```

How can I accomplish the same with the MDC?

Comment: Fast solution 
:host ::ng-deep .mdc-checkbox__background {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

More details get here :
https://material.angular.io/guide/mdc-migration

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tpp3zf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,package.json,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

Answer (score 2):

To change the checkbox size, add the following CSS in `styles.scss`:

```
.mdc-checkbox__background {
  width: 1.5rem !important;
  height: 1.5rem !important;
}
```

But this is only half of the solution if you want to use the default ripple effect. Now you also need to align the checkbox so that it fits nicely inside the ripple effect circle. Add the following CSS in `styles.scss`:

```
.mdc-checkbox__background {
  width: 1.5rem !important;
  height: 1.5rem !important;
  top: 50% !important; /* Added */
  left: 50% !important; /* Added */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) !important; /* Added */
}
```

See the [live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mwtpgt?file=src%2Fstyles.scss).

Answer (score 1):

The size and with of the mdc-checkbox is calculated by `--mdc-checkbox-state-layer-size`, with a default of `40px`:
[image: original mat style definitions]

So the easiest (and cleanest) way is to just override this variable as you like, e.g.

```
.mat-mdc-checkbox {
    --mdc-checkbox-state-layer-size: 25px;
  }
```